# Can't add anything to my second Form [C#-MetroFrameWorkUI]

Tags: c#

On my main Form "Form1" I can add Tabs and put Images, Buttons etc into it. But on my second Form "Champions" when I add Tabs and try put anything into a certain tab it prompts me with these errors. Its extremely hard to explain so its probably better if you look at the gif itself.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDGeo.png)
   [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DYZZ.png)

Gif of the error: https://i.imgur.com/wJwP4vT.gifv

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace League_Korean
{
    public partial class Champions : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        public Champions()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is [not better to post images of your IDE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode); we can't paste an image of code into our IDE or debug an image. Post [code that shows the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. And [pay attention to error messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/); yours tells you exactly what the problem is so don't ignore it.

Comment: Can share your App.config?

Comment: Added what both of you are looking for, sorry I'm not great at this. I haven't even written any code due to the fact I am being completely stopped from adding anything to my Form.

Comment: Your post seems extremely condescending Dour High Arch. I provided the error message and tried researching it myself first. Don't assume things about people. Obviously this is my last resort and that is extremely unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to the "TabPage Collection Editor", when I was pressing "add" to add mass amount of pages it was adding default WinForms Tab Pages instead of Metro Tab Pages.

Gif of what was happening: https://i.imgur.com/Gn7Wh7T.gifv